# Need help in generating REGEX for multi line JSON format

Tags: json, regex

From the below JSON data, I want to cut out the attributes object and keep only Name of the Account. Sample JSON

```
{  
    "Accounts":[  
        {  
            "attributes":{  
            "type":"Account",
            "url":"/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Account/001S0000008mgjpIAA"
            },
            "Name":"Name+Test#Reseller"
        },
        {  
            "attributes":{  
            "type":"Account",
            "url":"/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Account/001S000000m5gyuIAA"
        },
            "Name":"Test Reseller Myself"
        }
    ]
}
```

After matching with REGEX and replacing with "". The JSON should look like,

```
{
    "Accounts" : [{
        "Name" : "Name+Test#Reseller"
        }, {
        "Name" : "Test Reseller Myself"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Parsing JSON via regex isn't really a good idea

Comment: Am trying to replace in Notepad++ editor

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and return only `name` property value

```
obj.accounts = obj.accounts.map( s => {Name: s.Name } );
```

Comment: Am trying to replace it in Notepad++

Comment: In that case, remove javascript tag from your question.

Comment: You can copy your object in a browser's console and run this code over it.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself an answer. I constructed a two regex

```
1. "attributes" : {\w*\W*\d*\D*\d*.\d*\D*\w*"\w*
2. {.\s*\S*
```